# Тестрование REST-контроллеров без предварительного старта приложения

Tags: java, spring, юнит-тесты, rest, controller

Стоит задача написать тесты для REST-контроллеров. Хорошо бы избежать предварительного запуска приложения перед запуском тестов и найти такую платформу/фреймворк, чтобы сама "поднимала" нужную часть приложения и сама "дергала" указанный вызов (т.е. отправляла POST- или GET-запрос с указанными параметрами) и получала результат.

То, что мне удается найти, требует предварительного запуска всего приложения, и я даже не очень понимаю, по каким словам гуглить, чтобы найти то, что мне надо. Порекомендуйте, пожалуйста, тестовые платформы, которым не нужно запущенное приложение и которые умеют тестировать контроллеры, и понятные статьи/примеры. За объяснение, что в каком порядке при запуске теста должно происходить, тоже буду благодарна.

Пример метода, который надо протестировать:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/get")
public Voucher getVoucherById(
        @RequestParam(value = "voucherId", required = true) Long voucherId) {
    log.trace("getVoucherById: voucherId={}", voucherId);
    return voucherDAO.getVoucherById(voucherId);
}
```

Класс VoucherController, содержащий метод, помечен аннотацией @RestController

И еще - кто-нибудь работал с REST Assured? Она такое умеет?

Comment: [Spring test framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework)

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день!

Есть возможность без поднятия всего приложения, а только контроллера, тестировать его, при этом, вместо контроллера будет его mock,

примерно так будет выглядеть класс:

```
class TestVoucherController {
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Mock
private VoucherDAO voucherDAO;

@InjectMocks
private VoucherController voucherController;

@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
        .standaloneSetup(voucherController)
        .build();
}
@Test
public void getVoucherById() {
    Voucher voucher = new Voucher(1L, "name");
    when(voucherDAO.getVoucherById(1L)).thenReturn(voucher);

    mockMvc.perform(
        get("/get?voucherId=1")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(voucher)))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

    verify(voucherDAO, times(1)).getVoucherById(voucher);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(voucherDao);
}}
```

Зависимости pom:

```
<!--Spring test-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

ссылочка, может помочь:
https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/unit-testing-of-spring-mvc-controllers-normal-controllers/